# Detect versionNumber from MyProject-App.xml? Adobe AIR

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, adobe, flash-builder

The desktop application I'm working on is being developed in Adobe AIR + Flex + As3. Now I want to detect the versionNumber parameter on the accompanying XML description file for the AIR app.

```
<!-- A string value of the format <0-999>.<0-999>.<0-999> that represents application version which can be used to check for application upgrade. 
Values can also be 1-part or 2-part. It is not necessary to have a 3-part value.
An updated version of application must have a versionNumber value higher than the previous version. Required for namespace >= 2.5 . -->
<versionNumber>1.0.0</versionNumber>
```

Is there a variable or property that I can use to access this? For example in the About box of the app, instead of manually editing the version displayed, I want it to rely on this one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
  var appXML:XML =  NativeApplication.nativeApplication.applicationDescriptor;
```

you can parse version number from this xml , like this

```
var ns:Namespace = appXML.namespace();
trace(appXML.ns::versionNumber);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use applicationDescriptor property from NativeApplication class to get the application descriptor xml http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/reference/html/flash/desktop/NativeApplication.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use not just numbers - 2.1.1 - and put alpha/beta... you must use the "versionLabel" not the "versionNumber"

```
var xml:XML = NativeApplication.nativeApplication.applicationDescriptor;
var ns:Namespace = xml.namespace();
var version:String = xml.ns::versionLabel;
```